# How to find out what types are returned in promises Java script

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, typescript, stripe-payments

I am trying to use stripe for the payment solution for my client.

here is the example code strait from documentation im trying to use:

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_uTzXlltbjYmk6FISYoooBvFo");

stripe.accounts.retrieve(
  "acct_1DEnU3AqtajnnBvl",
  function(err, account) {
   // asynchronously called
 }
);
```

when I try to do error handling the err param is of type any, and I cant find out how to log what error is actually occurring. jumping to def doesn't seem to work either. I just want to see what my error is.

Here is link to docs:

https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=node#create_account

Comment: Hello - not using it at the moment but did you try to add the stripe typings? you can found them here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/stripe

Comment: Just add `console.log(err);` to your callback?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen it just shows [object] as type any but good suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the typings, the callbacks are of type [`IResponseFn<R>`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a124861bbf2c25426b13d65774b1d728ca9ec043/types/stripe/index.d.ts#L7350), which takes an error parameter of type [`IStripeError`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a124861bbf2c25426b13d65774b1d728ca9ec043/types/stripe/index.d.ts#L7578).

If you have `@types/stripe` installed and import the Stripe API using `import`, TypeScript should be able to tell you this.  In this case, you should use the special import-assignment syntax for modules with a CommonJS-style export assignment:

```
import stripeFactory = require("stripe");
var stripe = stripeFactory("sk_test_uTzXlltbjYmk6FISYoooBvFo");
```

If you have the `esModuleInterop` compiler option enabled, the following should also work:

```
import stripeFactory from "stripe";
var stripe = stripeFactory("sk_test_uTzXlltbjYmk6FISYoooBvFo");
```

Let me know if it doesn't work.